# Is there any Image processing library for Python 2.5 that does not require external dependencies under Windows?

Tags: python

I observed that there are (too) many ImageMagick libraries for Python but I found none that can just be installed and that will include the ImageMagick libraries.

I am looking for something can be be easily installed and that has to work with Python 2.5 (please, don't ask me why 2.5!)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try the [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)? They have got an installer for Python 2.5 and I don't think there are further dependencies.

Comment: Yes, PIL was my first option for a very short time. In half an hour I found out that it is not able to read some BMP files, including those made with Paint.

Comment: PIL is able to read BMP no problem.  Try using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` and `im = plt.imread('yourfile.bmp')` to load into an array.

Answer (score 0):

I won't ask you why 2.5, don't worry - but I am pretty happy with [Python Imaging Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

I work mostly on Windows, and while PIL has its glitches, it works just fine. Up to now I haven't had any compatibility problems BMPs, JPGs and PNGs.

I suggest you look into PIL once again, I just tried to make a BMP in Paint and it works fine.

BTW, a thing that can make stuff seem inoperable is forgetting to put "wb" as file output mode when saving using the Image.save() function.